# JMF unable to add a Capture Device

Tags: windows, device, webcam, jmf

I am trying to capture video via JMStudio.

When I try to run jmfinit it can detect my webcam and ask to select a video device and then exits without any error. But the device is not listed in jmfregistry.

When I try to add a device manually it is giving me an error
`Could not add item`

I have tried to run both (jmfinit and jmfregistry) as administrator and even tried to change the security settings but nothing seems to work.

I am using Windows 7 on my Sony Vaio laptop.